# Расчет расстояния по нескольким координатам python

Tags: python, numpy, координаты, geopy

Имеется два массива с широтой и долготой.

```py
lat = np.array([])
lon = np.array([])
```

Необходимо рассчитать расстояние между каждой точкой и сложить их.
Само расстояние вычисляется с помощью geopy.

```py
dist = distance.geodesic(mark1, mark2, ellipsoid='WGS-84').m
```

---

Обновлено:
strawdog, спасибо за ответ!

Но всё же получается, что он считает разницу числом из первого массива и второго.

Поэтому переделал, вот рабочий вариант:

```py
sum_distance = 0
for i in range(len(lat)):
    mark1 = (lat[i-1], lon[i-1])
    mark2 = (lat[i], lon[i])
    if i > 0: # Для того, чтобы исключить суммирование с последней координаты
        sum_distance += distance.geodesic(mark1, mark2, ellipsoid='WGS-84').km
    else:
        sum_distance = 0
```

В результате вывод:

> 0
>   0,4
>   0,8
>   ...
>   13,2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вероятно, так:

```
from geopy.distance import geodesic
import numpy as np

lat = np.array([22.5726, 28.7041, 6.9270])
lon = np.array([88.3639, 77.1025, 79.8612])

dist = 0
for i in range(len(lat)):
    dist += geodesic(lat[i], lon[i], ellipsoid='WGS-84').m

print(dist)
```

> 20810835.3369049